# wpf mvvm last used listbox on view from viewmodel code

Tags: list, mvvm, treeview, viewmodel

In WPF by using MVVM architecture. Is it possible to determine from ViewModel which was the last used ListBox on the corresponding View?

I've got 2 ListBoxes and a TreeView. The listboxes are containing different types of lists, and I want to use them to create composite data into the TreeView.

I would like to have version in which I can choose between the two ListBoxes, and the TreeView, because I have operations for the TreeView too..

Thx for help!

Comment: Can you define, or expand on, what you mean by "last used"? Do you mean the last ListBox that was added to, the last one clicked on, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

For simple, you can introduce any flag within viewmodel, which will be turned on/off when specified ListBox`s SelectedItem changed.
something like

private bool _isFirstBoxWasLastChanged;

```
object FirstListSelectedItem
{
     get { return _fSelectedItem;}
    set {
         _fSelectedItem = value;
         _isFirstBoxWasLastChanged = true;
         RaisePropertyChanged("FirstListSelectedItem");
        }
}

object SecondListSelectedItem
{
     get { return _sSelectedItem;}
    set {
         _sSelectedItem = value;
         _isFirstBoxWasLastChanged = false;
         RaisePropertyChanged("SecondListSelectedItem");
        }
}
```

ofc. it will be work if you use bindings for SelectecItem property.

Comment: I would like to have version in which I can choose between the two ListBoxes, and the TreeView, because I have operations for the TreeView too..

Comment: Dmitry's answer can easily be modified to cope with a TreeView as well. Perhaps you should try it?

Answer (score 0):

You might check the selected change to see who was the last ListBox

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lstItens}" SelectedItem="{Binding itemSelected}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lstItensTwo}" SelectedItem="{Binding itemSelectedTwo}" />
</StackPanel>
```

On your viewModel:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string vmFlagType;
    public string VmFlagType
    {
        get { return vmFlagType; }
        set
        {
            vmFlagType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VmFlagType");
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<string> lstItens;
    public ObservableCollection<string> LstItens
    {
        get { return lstItens; }
        set
        {
            lstItens = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LstItens");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> lstItensTwo;
    public ObservableCollection<string> LstItensTwo
    {
        get { return lstItensTwo; }
        set
        {
            lstItensTwo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LstItensTwo");
        }
    }

    private string itemSelected;
    public string ItemSelected
    {
        get { return itemSelected; }
        set
        {
            itemSelected = value;
            VmFlagType = flagTypes.ListOne;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemSelected");
        }
    }

    private string itemSelectedTwo;
    public string ItemSelectedTwo
    {
        get { return itemSelectedTwo; }
        set
        {
            itemSelectedTwo = value;
            VmFlagType = flagTypes.ListTwo;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemSelectedTwo");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Just create a class to assis you deciding which List was changed for the last time:

```
public class flagTypes
{
    public const string ListOne = "ListOne";
    public const string ListTwo = "ListTwo";
}
```